# I want to get an output of the find command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Am trying to write a script that finds the files that are older than 10 hours from the sub-directories that are in the "HS_client_list". And send the Output to a file "find.log".

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do

  echo Executing cd /moveit/$line
  cd /moveit/$line

  #Find files less than 600 minutes old.
  find $PWD -type f -iname "*.enc" -mmin +600 -execdir basename '{}' ';' | xargs ls > /home/infa91punv/find.log


done < HS_client_list
```

However, the script is able to cd to the folders from HS_client_list(this file contents the name of the subdirectories) but, the find command (`find $PWD -type f -iname "*.enc" -mmin +600 -execdir basename '{}' ';' | xargs ls > /home/infa91punv/find.log`) is not working. The Output file is empty. But when I run `find $PWD -type f -iname "*.enc" -mmin +600 -execdir basename '{}' ';' | xargs ls > /home/infa91punv/find.log` as a command it works and from the script it doesn't.

Comment: `>` you know that you _overwrite_ the file each loop? `as a command it works` does it find any files when using _the last_ entry from HS_client_list? And, check your script with shellcheck.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the file in each iteration.

You can use `xargs` to perform `find` on multiple directories; but you have to use an alternate delimiter to avoid having `xargs` populate the `{}` in the `-execdir` command.

```
sed 's%^%/moveit/%' HS_client_list | 
xargs -I '<>' find '<>' -type f -iname "*.enc" -mmin +600 -execdir basename {} \; > /home/infa91punv/find.log
```

The `xargs ls` did not seem to perform any useful functionality, so I took it out. Generally, [don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

With GNU `find`, you could avoid the call to an external utility, and use the `-printf` predicate to print just the part of the path name that you care about.

For added efficiency, you could invoke a shell to collect the arguments:

```
sed 's%^%/moveit/%' HS_client_list | 
xargs sh -c 'find "$@" -type f -iname "*.enc" -mmin +600 -execdir basename {} \;' _ >/home/infa91punv/find.log
```

This will run as many directories as possible in a single `find` invocation.

If you want to keep your loop, the solution is to put the redirection after `done`.  I would still factor out the `cd`, and [take care to quote the variable interpolation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  find /moveit/"$line" -type f -iname "*.enc" -mmin +600 -execdir basename '{}' ';' 
done < HS_client_list >/home/infa91punv/find.log
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you run `-execdir basename {} \;` -- in my brief experiments, you could replace that with simply `-execdir echo {} \;` or perhaps more efficiently and elegantly `-execdir printf '%s\n' {} +`

Comment: It looks to me like the `xargs ls` part is not merely unnecessary, but actively problematic, since the `ls` will not be running in the right directory. `-execdir` will run `basename` (or `echo` or whatever) in the file's directory, but that doesn't apply to `xargs` or `ls`.

Comment: Also `find` can take more than one directory at a time to search, so in theory you could do this (untested) `find $(sed 's%^%/moveit/%' HS_Client_List) -type f ... `.

Comment: @AnthonyCHowe The second `xargs` example already does exactly that, but avoids the problems with using a command substitution, which won't work if the paths contain unquoted whitespace or shell metacharacters.